How to Load Balancing External API Calls in spring gateway
Is it possible to distribute the load of external API calls in spring gateway? I have third-party APIs located in different regions. My goal is to evenly distribute calls to these APIs across regions in a round-robin fashion, considering each region's specific rate limit.
tried these spring gateway yml configruations:
# Spring gateway config try 1 spring: cloud: gateway: routes: - id: external-route-test uri: lb://external-route-lb predicates: - Path=/external-lb/actuator/health filters: - StripPrefix=1 loadbalancer: type: roundrobin servers: - https://external-service1.com - https://external-service2.com - https://external-service3.com
# Spring gateway config try 2 spring: cloud: discovery: client: simple: # SimpleDiscoveryClient to configure statically  services instances: external-route-lb: - uri: https://external-service1.com - uri: https://external-service2.com gateway: routes: - id: external-route-test uri: lb://external-route-lb predicates: - Path=/external-api-lb/actuator/health filters: - StripPrefix=1

You may want to give a try to zoned-based load-balancing for your load-balancer configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/loadbalancer.html#zone-based-load-balancing
